# Run on the go changing CMD command using C++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, system

The goal of this piece of code is to run a CMD command on Windows that can be set by the user (e.g cd *path*).
It's not just about moving through directories which would be much easier using pure c++.
I've written this and the key is in 'system("cd %s", path);' but I can't figure out any way to make it work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path;
    cout << "Path: ";
    cin >> path;
    system("cd %s", path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system("cd %s", path);` `system()` doesn't work like `printf()`.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking if there's any way to make it

Comment: For `cd` no, there's no way.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the *chdir()* system call instead of trying to employ CMD.

Comment: The choice of `cd` as your test command was unfortunate: it won't have any visible effect, because it affects only the `cmd.exe` process (which then promptly exits anyway).  Your process won't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a `c_str()` member function that returns a `char*` pointing to the text, so that it can be used in contexts that take a `char*` instead of a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

First, save "cd " in a std::string. After that, just use std::string::append to append the path the user enters into the console. Then just call `system(pathVar);`

Comment: 2 things: You should note that [`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) doesn't take a `std::string` parameter. With `cd` the `system()` call has no effect.

Comment: @Kenneth Clark: I tried that and I get the error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int system(const char*)'